# Designing a navbar, how to increase the size of the hovered field with css?

Tags: html, css

My header looks like this:

[image]

If I hover over it, it increases slightly, to this:

[image]

What property needs to be changed in the CSS so that on-hovering it takes the entire height of the blue bar? I tried using `width` since I am using `border-box`, I thought the size of the blue bar wont change but it did.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-bar {
  background: rgb(3, 50, 112);
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-bar ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-bar ul li {
  width: 120px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.active,
.menu-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #2bab0b;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet1" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">


<div class="menu-bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Training </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

---

Edit :

As was suggested in the comment. I included `height:30px;` in the hover class as including it in `menu-bar` class did not seem to work. However what seems to be happening is that the size of green highlight is increasing while and the size of the blue bar:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the effect you are looking for ? See the code snippet below. I removed that margin from `li` and added a padding on `a`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-bar {
  background: rgb(3, 50, 112);
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-bar ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
    
}

.menu-bar ul li {
  width: 120px;
}

.menu-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display:block;
  padding:15px;
 
}
.active,
.menu-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #2bab0b;
  border-radius: 3px;

}
```

```html
<div class="menu-bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Training </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove margin from `li`.

```css
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position : center;
    
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-bar
{
    background: rgb(3, 50, 112);
    text-align: center;
}


ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 0px;    
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #2bab0b;
  border-radius: 3px;  
}

.active {
  background-color: #2bab0b;
  border-radius: 3px;  
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Title of page    </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet1" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    </head>


    <body> 
        <div class="menu-bar">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for. I **modified** your code and added some `transition` on `hovering`. Look at the following code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url(background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.menu-bar {
  background: rgb(3, 50, 112);
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-bar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-bar ul li {
  padding: 10px 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-bar:hover li {
  padding: 14px 12px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.menu-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.active,
.menu-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #2bab0b;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet1" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/css/fontawesome.min.css">


<div class="menu-bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Training </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: With transition though the size of the buttons are increasing. Is there any way that could be fix size with the transition?